# Valor no deseado al imprimir el valor de un JComboBox en un JTable - Java

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

Tengo un `Jtable` (`tbDocSolicitud`) que es llenado con información de la base de datos `Sql Server 2008 R2`. Presenta 10 columnas y en la primera columna hay un `CheckBox` y en la segunda columna hay un ComboBox que es llenado desde la base de datos, el problema es que cuando voy marcando las filas del Jtable y a la vez voy seleccionando el combobox y cuando le doy click al boton enviar, no me imprime el valor del combobox osea su código si no me sale su nombre del combobox.

Este es el código donde lleno el JComboBox:

```
void CargarCentroCostoDestino() throws Exception{
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            combo = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Objeto>();
            cn = new SqlConexion().getConectar();
            String sql = "Select c_ccosto, x_ccosto from fccosto";
            pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            combo.addElement(new Objeto("0", "Seleccione"));
            while(rs.next()){
                combo.addElement(new Objeto(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
            }
            cboCentroCostoDestino.removeAllItems();
            cboCentroCostoDestino.setModel(combo);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if (rs != null)
                    rs.close();
                if (pstm != null)
                    pstm.close();
                if (cn != null)
                    cn.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Esta es la clase Objeto:

```
public class Objeto {
    private String codigo;
    private String nombre;

    public Objeto(String codigo, String nombre){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Objeto() {}

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

Este es el código del boton enviar:

```
protected void btnEnviarActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int cont = 0;
        Boolean checked = false;
        Objeto object = new Objeto();
        for(int i = 0; i < tbDocSolicitud.getRowCount(); i++){
            checked = Boolean.valueOf(tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            object.setCodigo(tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            String cod_centroCostoDestino = object.getCodigo();
            if(checked == true){
                cont++;
                System.out.println(cod_centroCostoDestino);
            }
        }
        if(cont == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Marque los documentos que desea solicitar");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza la linea-->    combo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
por:

```
     combo = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Objeto>(){
        public String toString() {
            return this.getSelectedItem() != null ? this.getSelectedItem().toString() : null;   
        }
    };
```